# Interface genérica

Tags: c#

Estou criando um Web-Service `WCF` que irá expor métodos para fazer operações CRUD em uma base de dados. E estou com dúvidas em como criar a interface de contrato.
O Serviço possibilitará CRUD em várias tabelas e envolverá muito tipos complexos como `Client`, `Address`, `Dependent`, `Functionary`, etc.
Criei a interface de contrato chamada `IDataPersistance` e por enquanto está assim:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IDataPersistance
{
    [OperationContract]
    bool Insert ( object value );

    [OperationContract]
    bool Change ( object value );

    [OperationContract]
    bool Delete ( object value );

    // TODO: Adicione suas operações de serviço aqui
}
```

O problema é que para inserir um **Cliente** o método `Insert` deve receber um objeto `Client`, para inserir um **Endereço** o método `Insert` deve receber um objeto `Address`, assim por diante.
O mesmo também acontece como método `Delete`. Em alguns casos (como para deletar um **Endereço**) ele recebe uma `string` como parâmetro e em outros casos um `int`.
Estou pesando em como eu poderia criar uma interface (genérica ?) que sirva de contrato para operações de CRUD que envolvam qualquer tipo.

Ou nesse caso eu não tenho como fugir e terei que criar uma interface CRUD para cada objeto que será persistido no banco? Ou seja, uma interface para CRUD de **Clientes**, outra para CRUD de **Dependentes**, etc. ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não sei se entendi muito bem sua dúvida, mas acho que uma solução seria criar uma interface com métodos genéricos, fazendo com que suas classes Client, Address, Dependent, etc herdem dessa interface, implementando assim esses métodos.

Fonte: http://www.devmedia.com.br/criando-interfaces-genericas-em-c/23633

Comment: Ótimo!
Também, descobri que pode-se restringir onde o tipo genérico pode ser usando, se somente no retorno ou somente nos parâmetros [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/mt654058.aspx).